# My flex is displaying six divs in row instead of three?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is that i want three divs in a row instead of six, i set the `width` of whole section to **80%** and the `width` of each section to **26,66667%** which is 80/3 but my `display: flex` is not working properly

Here is my code:

```css
body,
html {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section_wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 26.666667%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.section1 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section2 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section3 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section4 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section5 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section6 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section1 h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.section3 h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.section5 h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="section_wrapper">
  <div class="section section1">
    <h3>About me</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section section3">

  </div>

  <div class="section section3">
    <h3>Work</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section section4">

  </div>

  <div class="section section5">
    <h3>Services</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section section6">

  </div>
</div>
```

By the way this is the **design** i'm trying to code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `flex-wrap:wrap` using it will wrap when there is not more space for the children to expand

And you can use `flex-basis: calc(100%/3)` instead of that weird `width`

See a good article about `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body,
html {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section_wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 calc(100%/3);
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.section1 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section2 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section3 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section4 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section5 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section6 {
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
.section1 h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.section3 h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.section5 h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="section_wrapper">
  <div class="section section1">
    <h3>About me</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section section3">

  </div>

  <div class="section section3">
    <h3>Work</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section section4">

  </div>

  <div class="section section5">
    <h3>Services</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section section6">

  </div>
</div>
```